# How do you return custom errors from CakePHP AuthComponent?

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am currently adding a CakePHP 3 Authentication component to and existing CakePHP application following the documentation listed here:

https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/components/authentication.html

I am currently handling the display of error messages, following this example:

https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Username or password is incorrect'));
        }
    }
}
```

I am integrating the auth components following the documentation here, where an array of user data is returned if a user is able to be authenticated and false if they are not (as specified in the docs):

https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authentication-objects

```
namespace App\Auth;

use Cake\Auth\BaseAuthenticate;
use Cake\Http\ServerRequest;
use Cake\Http\Response;

class OpenidAuthenticate extends BaseAuthenticate
{
    public function authenticate(ServerRequest $request, Response $response)
    {
        // Do things for OpenID here.
        // Return an array of user if they could authenticate the user,
        // return false if not.

        if($failureCondition) {
            return false;
        }

        return $user;
    }
}
```

However I would like to dynamically determine the error in the auth component:

```
namespace App\Auth;

use Cake\Auth\BaseAuthenticate;
use Cake\Http\ServerRequest;
use Cake\Http\Response;

class OpenidAuthenticate extends BaseAuthenticate
{
    public function authenticate(ServerRequest $request, Response $response)
    {
        if($failureConditionA) {
            $this->error = 'Error A'; 
            return false;
        }

        if($failureConditionB) {
            $this->error = 'Error B'; 
            return false;
        }

        return $user;
    }
}
```

And print the dynamically produced error in the flash message like so:

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            // 'Error A' or 'Error B' displayed on failure
            $this->Flash->error($this->Auth->error());
        }
    }
}
```

What is the correct code to use to do this?

If this violates the intention behind how the AuthComponent is supposed to function, I would be interested to have that explained and / or know any other correct ways to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no overly clean way of exposing error details, the whole auth component stuff was never specifically designed to return failure details.

There's lots of ways to solve this, the most simple one would probably be to obtain a specific authentication object, and access the errors that the object stored via a public API that it would need to implement, ie your authenticator could for example expose a `getError()` method, then you could something like this in your controller:

```php
$openIdAuth = $this->Auth->getAuthenticate('Openid');
$error = $openIdAuth->getError();
```

For something a little more sophisticated you could implement a custom/extended authentication component, where you have access to the complete list of authentication objects and can easily access the last one in the chain and return possible error information that it holds.

If you're implementing authentication into an application that doesn't yet use any authentication, then I'd very, very strongly recommend that you ditch the deprecated auth component, and use the new [**authentication plugin**](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/1/en/index.html) instead! It's way cleaner and much more versatile, and [**returning error details**](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/1/en/authentication-component.html#checking-the-login-status) is supported out of the box.

Comment: Thanks, so how would you set the you set the error using that method in the Auth Component? I would be happy to use another authentication plugin, but I am currently using this the extend a pre-existing authentication system that was written a while back.

Comment: @space97Not sure what exactly you are referring to with regards to usage in the auth component?

Comment: Sorry I was not that clear. You mentioned this in your answer: "access the errors that the object stored via a public API". I am wondering how the errors are logged to the Auth Component object? In my mock up code "I used $this->error = 'Error A'";  in the Auth Component to demonstrate this. I am new to Cake so I am still figuring out some of the conventions.

Comment: @space97 There's not really a CakePHP convention to this, you're not doing anything to the auth component itself, but to an authenticator that the component can use! That distinction is important when talking about this in order to prevent confusion. Building up on your example, I ment to simply add a `getError()` method to your authenticator that would return the value of the `error` property, ie something like `public function getError() { return $this->error; }`, which you could then call as shown in the example in my answer.